# Best practice for an ActiveRecord object that updates another ActiveRecord object on save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, callback

here's my situation: I have two ActiveRecord models:

```
class SomeAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :moderation
end

class Moderation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_action
end
```

I would like Moderation to update SomeAction's status attribute to "complete" when I save the moderation associated with it.  I would like the moderation to NOT save if for some reason the update to SomeAction was unsuccessful.  I know I should be doing this in the before_save callback, however returning false (after realizing that the SomeAction record was not updatable) will not ROLLBACK everything.  Any ide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use :autosave which will automatically validate the associated model fo ryou.

```
class SomeAction < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :moderation
end

class Moderation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_action, :autosave => true

  before_validation do |moderation|
    moderation.some_action.complete # Changes state
  end

  # autosave kicks in and validates the associated record
  # If validation for some_action fails, the error messages will be pulled up in Moderation
end
```

More info in [activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/autosave_association.rb#L154), or the [Rails documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your table support transactions (i.e. MySQL InnoDB), then do the following:

```
class Moderation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :some_action

  def do_save
    transaction do
      some_action.status = 'complete'
      some_action.save!
      save!
    end
  end

end
```